# Probability (Uniform, exponential, or something else?)

Tags: probability-distributions

I want to find the distribution of the question.

A student uses a computer for an average of 10 minutes. Let X denote the amount of time that a student uses the computer in a single session.

Confusing me with distribution and parameter.

Comment: It is not clear what a suitable model might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exponential is OK, since there is no upper bound on time spent on PC by one student. Now [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) has one parameter $\lambda$ and its expected value is $\lambda^{-1}$ can you know count the parameter $\lambda$?

Comment: Yeah I was thinking exponential too, using λ = 1/10. But the definition of exponential confused me as in time until the first success does not seem to fit this problem very well. is λ=1/10 correct?

Comment: You can think that success = "leaving the computer". Your $\lambda$ is correct.

Comment: oh ok. Thank you! the wording just confused me for a bit there.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting the answer = closing the question to let others know that you've got your answer.